# Задача на Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста. Я уже голову сломал. 
Есть задача: "Напишите программу, которая запрашивает число N, далее последовательность из N чисел, и выводит сумму всех элементов.".

Все бы ничего. Но. Как обработать случай, когда числа подаются не из арифметической последовательности от 1 до n, а рандомные n чисел?

У меня есть это, но это работает только с арифметической прогрессией.
С рандомными числами не правильно работает.
Извиняюсь, что не через пасту зашарил.

```
import java.util.* 

val scan = Scanner(System.`in`) 

fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
var sum = 0 
val n = scan.nextInt() 
for (i in 1..n) sum += i 
print(sum) 
}
```

Comment: Этот код работает не так, как написано. Где-то нашел, небось, а что он делает не знаешь.

Comment: Я знаю как он работает. Он берет число n с клавиатуры, и выводит сумму чисел арифметической прогрессии от 1 до n. Если n = 5, то он и выводит сумму чисел (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), то есть - 15. И так далее. В этом и был затык, что я не знал, как обрабатывать рандомный диапазон, а не прогрессию. Ну, тут ещё авторам курса спасибо сказать надо. Там такие задания попадаются, что только чтоб понять что от тебя хотят, без бутылки не управиться.

Comment: В вопросе написано, что программа делает другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.* 

val scan = Scanner(System.`in`) 

fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
   var sum = 0 
   val n = scan.nextInt() 
   for (i in 1..n) { //запрашиваем n чисел
      sum+=scan.nextInt() 
   }
   print(sum) 
}
```

Comment: Это, разве, сработает? К примеру, n присвоили число 5. Затем ввели n чисел. Если ввели 1 2 3 4 5, то сумма получается 15. Этот вариант проходит тест. А если подают 4 и 4 4 4 4, то сумма получается 10, почему то. А должна быть 16. Вот ссылка на задачу: https://stepik.org/lesson/75492/step/9?unit=54659

Comment: Да, не проходит такой код. На тесте с рандомными числами валится

Comment: Не знаю - у меня все проходит

Comment: @Amavite, если поставить косые апострофы вокруг in, то все заработает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbDyQ.png

Comment: Так просто? Надо мне, пожалуй, передышку взять) спасибо за помощь)